# Got interpolation Error Angular

Tags: angularjs

Error

compiler.js:24661 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{productData.images[0]}}] in ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58 ("iv class="col-sm-4">

][src]={{productData.images[0]}} [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">

"): ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{productData.images[0]}}] in ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58 ("iv class="col-sm-4">

][src]={{productData.images[0]}} [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">

"): ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 24 in [{{productData.images[0]}}] in ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58 ("iv class="col-sm-4">

][src]={{productData.images[0]}} [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">

"): ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 24 in [{{productData.images[0]}}] in ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58 ("iv class="col-sm-4">

][src]={{productData.images[0]}} [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">

"): ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58
Parser Error: Unexpected token '}' at column 25 in [{{productData.images[0]}}] in ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58 ("iv class="col-sm-4">

][src]={{productData.images[0]}} [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height">

"): ng:///SidebarModule/ProductDetailComponent.html@9:58

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the HTML so we can take a look? Preferably HTML and the portion of the javascript.